# How to center all elements from top to bottom in a GridPane

Tags: javafx

```
GridPane.setConstraints(button1,0,0);
GridPane.setConstraints(button2,0,1);
GridPane.setConstraints(button3,0,2);

gridPane.getChildren().addAll(button1,button2,button3);
```

I have some buttons in a GridPane as they are shown above, and I want to

1. center them all in `gridPane`;
2. center each button's label within
       their button boundary (optional).

Currently the buttons are aligned to the left and they don't look so good. Can someone please tell me what to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the vertical and horizontal alignments of each cell by using other constraint options:

```
GridPane.setConstraints( b1, 0, 0, 1, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER );
GridPane.setConstraints( b2, 0, 1, 1, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER );
GridPane.setConstraints( b3, 0, 2, 1, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER );
```

You may also set the gaps between the cells with:

```
gridPane.setVgap( 10 );
gridPane.setHgap( 10 );
```

to debug those values visually use:

```
gridPane.setGridLinesVisible( true );
```